# Solving Linear System with inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I have the following system:

> \begin{align}
> b - x = 0 \\
> a - 0.33b - 0.5x =0 \\ 
> d - 0.33b = 0 \\
> a - 0.33b + c = 0 \\
> a + b + c + d + 2x = 1 \\
> a + b + c + d - 8.8x \le 0 \\
> a + b + c + d - 7.27x \ge 0
> \end{align}

where a,b,c,d and x are unknown variables.

Is there any solution to this system and how to solve this system?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: actually I am new to this Linear programming and linear systems, so I help me out.

Comment: What do you know about $b$ and $x$?

Comment: As I said, a,b,c ,d and x are all unknown variables.

Comment: I will give you a hint. Is the 0.33 actually meant to be 1/3?

Comment: There are as many equalities as there are unknowns. Solve the equalities first, then check the remaining inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$x=b$$
$$d=0.33b$$
$$a=0.33b+0.5b=0.83b$$
$$c=0.33b-0.83b=-0.5b$$
one has
$$1=(0.83+1-0.5+0.33+2)b\Rightarrow b=\frac{1}{3.66}$$
Hence, 
$$a=\frac{0.83}{3.66},b=\frac{1}{3.66},c=-\frac{0.5}{3.66},d=\frac{0.33}{3.66},x=\frac{1}{3.66}.$$

However, $$a+b+c+d-7.27x=\frac{0.83+1-0.5+0.33-7.27}{3.66}=\frac{-5.61}{3.66}\color{red}{\lt} 0$$
so, the system has no solution.

Comment: Well done, but what about the inequalities ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thank you for pointing it out. I should have written about them.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

1. $b-x=0$, and thus $b=x$.
2. Now we have $a-0.5x-0.33b=0$, thus $a-0.5x-0.33x=0$, thus $a-0.83x=0$, and thus $a=0.83x$.
3. What do we know of $d$ in the form of $b$?

Answer (score 0):

No, this system has no solution.

The equations give a matrix

```
(%i) A;
                          [ 0    1     0  0   - 1  ]
                          [                        ]
                          [ 1  - 0.33  0  0  - 0.5 ]
                          [                        ]
(%o)                      [ 0  - 0.33  0  1    0   ]
                          [                        ]
                          [ 1  - 0.33  1  0    0   ]
                          [                        ]
                          [ 1    1     1  1    2   ]
```

with non-zero determinant $3.66$, so $A x = b$, with solution vector $b$

```
(%i) b;
                                     [ 0 ]
                                     [   ]
                                     [ 0 ]
                                     [   ]
(%o)                                 [ 0 ]
                                     [   ]
                                     [ 0 ]
                                     [   ]
                                     [ 1 ]
```

has exactly one solution $x$.

```
(%i) x;
                            [  0.22677595628415  ]
                            [                    ]
                            [  0.27322404371585  ]
                            [                    ]
(%o)                        [ - 0.13661202185792 ]
                            [                    ]
                            [ 0.090163934426229  ]
                            [                    ]
                            [  0.27322404371585  ]
```

Inserting this solution into the inequalities gives:

```
(%i) [1,1,1,1,-8.8] . x;
(%o)                        - 1.950819672131148
(%i) [1,1,1,1,-7.27] . x;
(%o)                        - 1.532786885245901
```

The first one ("$\le 0$") holds, the second one ("$\ge 0$") not.